# How to force AutoFixture to create ImmutableList

Tags: c#, autofixture

In System.Collections.Generic there is a very useful ImmutableList. But for this type Autofixture is throwing an exception because it doesn't have public constructor, it's being created like `new List<string>().ToImmutableList()`. How to tell AutoFixture to populate it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So thanks to @Mark Seemann I can now answer my question:

```
public class ImmutableListSpecimenBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        var t = request as Type;
        if (t == null)
        {
            return new NoSpecimen();
        }

        var typeArguments = t.GetGenericArguments();
        if (typeArguments.Length != 1 || typeof(ImmutableList<>) != t.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
        {
            return new NoSpecimen();
        }

        dynamic list = context.Resolve(typeof(IList<>).MakeGenericType(typeArguments));

        return ImmutableList.ToImmutableList(list);
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customizations.Add(new ImmutableListSpecimenBuilder());
var result = fixture.Create<ImmutableList<int>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create an extension for your tests and register `ImmutableHashSet<string>` to be created from `ImmutableHashSet<string>.Empty`.

```cs
public static class AutoFixtureExtensions
{
    public static Fixture DefaultCustomizations(this Fixture autofixture)
    {
        autofixture.Register(() => ImmutableHashSet<string>.Empty);
        return autofixture;
    }
}
```

And use it in your tests like this:

```cs
var result = new Fixture().DefaultCustomizations().Create<ImmutableList<int>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
fixture.Register((List<string> l) => l.ToImmutableList());
```

ought to do it.

Comment: Works great for string! Is it any way to make it generic for all types?

Comment: @user963935 That's a bit more involved, but you should be able to write an `ISpecimenBuilder` like [ListRelay](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/Kernel/ListRelay.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a nuget package to solve this:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Community.ImmutableCollections/#